# monit hostname is always localhost

Tags: monit

I've got monit running on a server to alert by email with the following config

```
set mailserver 127.0.0.1
 using hostname "vps1.sender.com"

set mail-format { from: monit@sender.com }

set alert webmaster@receiver.com
```

but the mails are still coming through with a hostname of **localhost**

```
 Aug  7 08:40:55 mx1 postfix/smtpd[31060]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
 vps1.sender.com[xx.xx.xx.xx]: 504 5.5.2 <localhost>: Helo command
 rejected: need fully-qualified hostname; from=<monit@sender.com>
 to=<webmaster@receiver.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost>
```

It's the only config file I have.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a configuration issue with postfix.

Make sure the `myhostname=` variable is set correctly in /etc/postfix/main.cf.  Apparently monit cant override that setting.

Answer (score 2):

In monitrc edit/add the line:

`check system vps1.sender.com`

and vps1.sender.com will be shown as the host on the email

Answer (score 1):

Monit uses `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` files for fqdn. If you did not setup those files, hostname file includes `localhost` line by default. You must change this to your fqdn and set `yourIP fqdn` in /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Both are set to vps1.sender.com

Comment: Does you subdomain registered in any DNS server? Or just named in server hosts file?

Comment: Maybe we both looking wrong place! What if problem caused by mail service? While I read second time it dawned on me. `<localhost>` is printed in `mail log`. I think you must check your mail service configuration.

Comment: I KNOW WHAT IT IS!! In postfix main.cf, it had `myhostname=localhost`  how annoying!  Thanks for your time though.